# Split String json

Tags: java, json, split

I have a **String** result=

```
{"fkcl":"5","fkdiv":["1","2","3","4","5"],"fkcl1":"3","fkdiv1":["1","2","3","4","5"]}
```

i want to **split** as

```
[{"fkcl":"5","fkdiv":["1","2","3","4","5"]}]
[{"fkcl1":"3","fkdiv":["1","2","3","4","5"]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the items always start with the string `"fkcl"`, you might be able to use a regular expression to do this. E.g.

```
String json = "{\"fkcl\":\"5\",\"fkdiv\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\"],\"fkcl1\":\"3\",\"fkdiv1\":[\"1\",\"2\",\"3\",\"4\",\"5\"]}";

String output = json
    .replaceAll("\\{?(\"fkcl)", "\n[{$1")
    .replaceAll(",\n", "}]\n") + "]";

System.out.println(output);
```

Produces:

```
[{"fkcl":"5","fkdiv":["1","2","3","4","5"]}]
[{"fkcl1":"3","fkdiv1":["1","2","3","4","5"]}]
```

Otherwise parse the string with a JSON parser (e.g. [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)) and then iterate over the elements and split when desired.